# How to simulate the behaviors of isError/isSuccess/data of useQuery Rtk Query using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'd like to build a custom hook useGetUserProfile like so:

```
export const useGetUserProfile = () => {
    const userInfo = useSelector(selectUserInfo)
    const isConnected = userInfo !== undefined
    return { userInfo: isConnected ? (userInfo as TUserInfo) : undefined, isConnected }
}
```

I'd like to do something so that when isConnected is verified, userInfo will become automatically not undefined (like the behaviors of isError/isSuccess/data of useQuery Rtk Query)

Do you guys no how to achieve this using Typescript? Thank you!

`(isConnected && userInfo.firstName ? ' ' + userInfo.firstName : '!')//give error 'userInfo' is possibly 'undefined'`

Answer (score 0):

the type inference works in the scope of the `useGetUserProfile()` function. the type inference is lost outside of this scope.

if you use a current version of typescript your example will just work. have a look at this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoFUDO0CSIYD2yA3gFDIXIhwC2EAXMpmFKAOYDcpAvqaTAFcQCMMAIhkA7AGUIAGwgiCUABQBKRhmxQ8hZAB9JIACYQYoCMZLlKUCGAFQJZSq6q0GyAEQApAgAsQLxsKXl5SCAAPAAdlMGQEcWZJbABxeyxoAAUoAnMFZABeZHUigD5rV0SQZKlcfCJiutkFJVU1Liqk+OBMAGFxEEVIKybtXSIAQkKmkzMLY07be0dnFPrCRl6BkCGRS2QAfnWdBoA6ajpkRiFTcyHjABpkbcHhg7C+AHov5AB3YBgfzIYy9BCsGigOAjIxiEB8KKxKDxaq1NIZbQ5PLABQAJiKJTU5UqlFR8Tqpz0YwgLWGynUSwoZJe-Te+1GJwmyGmszuC0ZLxgJVeu3exiJLjcFDsDicJUlUtcFImN3G50uEEeIUVFBFexG2tc3DU2u4yHk2BJUplq3lhsVyoaNzm90sWp1rj1YvtoRNRp4pCAA).

if you want to keep the inferred type connection between `isConnected` and `userInfo` outside of the function use a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html). you find an implementation in the playground.
the resulting return type is

```
{
    userInfo: string;
    isConnected: true;
} | {
    userInfo: undefined;
    isConnected: false;
}
```